# How to listen if textures from a GLTF model have loaded and have displayed? Three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, onload

So I have a GLTF model with a bin file loaded in canvas and I am wondering if there is a way to check if the textures have been loaded I have tried to detect it with:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){ 
alert('ready')
});
```

But this fires even before the GLTF file has loaded let alone the textures...

This also seems to trigger to soon before the textures show up in the canvas:

```
objImg = new Image();
objImg.src = 'Scene_-_Root_diffuse.jpg';
objImg.onload = function() {
alert('texture loaded');
}
```

any idea's ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: All resources of the `glTF` asset should be loaded when the `onLoad()` callback is fired. Doesn't this work for you?

Comment: @Mugen87 No it triggers well before

Comment: It seems to work without issues in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf_extensions. As you can see in the network tab of the browser's developer tools, the model is only added to the scene when all resources have been loaded.